# Склеить данные столбца Б по столбцу А

Tags: python-3.x

Наверно по названию не особо понятно)

Попробую расписать задачу, есть список:

```
http://asite.com|any_a1
http://asite.com|any_a2
http://asite.com|any_a3
http://bsite.com|any_b1
http://csite.com|any_c1
http://csite.com|any_c2
```

Список отсортирован по алфавиту (по сайтам), список может быть очень большим 1-10 млн. строк

В итоге нужно сравнить по первой части и если они равны склеить их вторые части)
Т.е. в итоге должен получиться список

```
any_a1|any_a2|any_a3
any_b1
any_c1|any_c2
```

Можно решить задачку на 3-ем питоне?

Answer (score 2):

Накидал пример простого парсера, 1кк ссылок лучше не выводить в консоль, а сразу в файл, кроме того парсер простой, поэтому сначала собирает список и упорядочивает, что не очень эффективно, но идея я думаю понятна:

```
sites = [
    'http://asite.com|any_a1',
    'http://asite.com|any_a2',
    'http://asite.com|any_a3',
    'http://bsite.com|any_b1',
    'http://csite.com|any_c1',
    'http://csite.com|any_c2',
]

from collections import defaultdict
name_by_list = defaultdict(list)

for site in sites:
    name = site.replace('http://', '').split('.')[0]
    any_value = site.split('|')[1]

    name_by_list[name].append(any_value)

# Сортировка по ключу
for name, any_list in sorted(name_by_list.items(), key=lambda x: x[0]):
    print('|'.join(any_list))
```

Консоль:

```
any_a1|any_a2|any_a3
any_b1
any_c1|any_c2
```

Answer (score 2):

Если список отсортирован и, следовательно, записи, относящиеся к одному сайту, всегда идут подряд, то я бы порекомендовал использовать groupby. Замерять лень, но, по идее, такое решение будет ощутимо быстрее, чем на словаре.

Кроме того, я использовал ленивый генератор, так что результат будет построчно писаться в файл по мере готовности - это позволит не хранить результат в памяти, что при миллионе строк может быть весьма приятным бонусом.

```
from itertools import groupby


sites = [
    'http://asite.com|any_a1',
    'http://asite.com|any_a2',
    'http://asite.com|any_a3',
    'http://bsite.com|any_b1',
    'http://csite.com|any_c1',
    'http://csite.com|any_c2',
]


cut = lambda s: s.split('|')
sitename = lambda tpl: tpl[0]

grouped = groupby(
                  map(cut, sites),
                  key=sitename
                  )

res = (
       '|'.join(
                [tpl[1] for tpl in grp]
               )
       for key, grp in grouped
  )

# Дальше мы итерируемся по res и поэлементно пишем результат в файл
```